# GIMP how to select from merged path

Tags: gimp

I have the path, merge from 8 subpath (because it require symmetry, I create 1/8 then merge them together)

[image]
[image]

I wanna select the picture inside the path, that is... impossible. Are there any ways to:

- re-order the points inside the path
  or
- manual set the points position (x and y coordinate)
  or
- unclose any subpath (I hate this, hate to do drawing the paths over again)
  or
- anyway it select inside the path smarter?

thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is splice the strokes so that you have a truly closed stroke from which you get a selection.

The [`ofn-path-edits` plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) has a `Join strokes` function to connect together strokes whose end points are close enough.

But you'll have to redo part of your work: use the `Join strokes` function to create the closed shapes, then replicate+shift these closed shapes. And yes, this means that between the shapes, there are overlapping strokes, one for the shape on the left/top and one for the shape on the right/bottom.

[At the same place](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) there is also a `path-mirror` script that can create the symmetry of a stroke, and connect the ends that are on the symmetry axis.